# Will adding indexes on an audit table negatively affects the performance of the create,edit,delete for our system functions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named Audit with the following fields; ID (PK), startDate,EndDate,TypeID.

I have added two indexes one on  the **StartDate** and the other on the **typeID** column . Since users can search the audit data based on these two columns. And a new audit record will be added to the audit table whenever a user perform add, edit or delete on any of our system functions. So my question is whether adding two indexes on the audit table can negatively affect the performance for adding, editing , deleting our system data inside our system, or since the audit table will only have new records added, no edit or deletion on the audit table , so adding the two indexes will not negatively affect the speed of the create, edit and delete for our data that will be logged ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Indexes are never free. The question is whether the cost of maintaining the two indexes will be noticeable at all, and if so, whether its impact on your write workload is justified by the improvements they make to the search queries.

My guess is going to be, yes, the indexes are probably worth it, but only you can know for sure by testing an entire workload cycle. (And assuming they are the right indexes to support your queries, which we also don't know.)

Comment: @MartinSmith That'll teach me not to skim. My mistake. +1 and I'll delete these noise comments